# Excel Power Query retrieving only 1000 rows when drilled down

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have created a pivot using powerquery connection in Excel. If I drill down the pivot values, it retrieves only 1000 records with a message "Data returned for  (First 1000 rows)"

Is there a way to extend this 1000 limit to show all the records?

Comment: Where do you see this message? In the Query Editor?

Comment: Not in editor... In excel sheet when you drill down on pivot

Answer (score 3):

According to [this post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/displaying-data-list-from-resuting-power-pivot-table/m-p/91563), you can adjust the limit by opening connection properties of your data model:

[image: Screenshot]

[This source](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/excel-2013-powerpivot-drilldown-is-limited-to-1000-rows-connection-can-not-be-edited-anymore.688551/) adds that the hard maximum number of rows is 1,048,576.

> Actually you can go well beyond the 1k limit. As a matter of fact you can go to 1,048,576 rows. The trick is
>
> 1. Place your mouse OUTSIDE of a pivot table
> 2. Click the DATA menu
> 3. Click Connections
> 4. In the Workbook Connections dialogue box click "ThisWorkbookDataModel"
> 5. Click Properties. In the Usage tab, “Maximum number of records to retrieve”

Comment: Does this work even if I share the workbook to others? Or this setting needs to be done by everyone who uses it?

Comment: I'd guess it would be saved with the file but you should test it.